# Creating an 2D Array from database table

Tags: android, sqlite, multidimensional-array

Could someone present me the simpliest way to pass the data from sqlite table to 2D array?

Lets assume table with columns: _id, date, value

I assume I have to count records in the table before I define an array

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would usually do this is by creating a Struct with the necessary properties (id, 
date, value in your case), and then have an array to hold the instances of the struct.

Comment: yeah, I know the theory, just need some simple example to put something bigger into test (I'm still finding hard creating multidimensional arrays, I think it requires some kind of multidimensional thinking :P )